# magento categories not showing on add product page?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, categories, magmi

I am currently developing a website, juggernet.com. juggernet.com is almost a duplicate of ooplo.com, in which it has the same products. To import the products i used the magmi import tool with the on the fly category importer/creater enabled.

All the categories are the but unfortuantely don't appear on the add product page of magento?

Here is a picture:

http://juggernet.com/magentoimages/productpage.png

and as you can see, all my categories are on the categories page:

http://juggernet.com/magentoimages/categoriespage.png

has this happened to you before?

Thanks Kieren.

Comment: Go to the root category, and click Save Category.  See if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can think is if the isActive is set No in general settings of all categories..